# Restructure dataframe based on given keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working on a dataset and after all the cleaning and restructuring I have arrived at a situation where the dataset looks like below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype={'freq_no': object, 'sequence': object, 'field': object})
print(df)
```

**CSV URL:** https://pastebin.com/raw/nkDHEXQC

```
          id  year period freq_no sequence  file_date  data_date  field  \
0  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180331  05210   
1  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180331  05210   
2  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180331  05210   
3  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180330  05220   
4  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180330  05220   
5  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180330  05230   
6  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180330  05230   

   value note_type            note transaction_type  
0  200.0       NaN             NaN                A  
1    NaN         B   {05210_B:ABC}                A  
2    NaN         U  {05210_U:DEFF}                D  
3  200.0       NaN             NaN                U  
4    NaN         U   {05220_U:xyz}                D  
5  100.0       NaN             NaN                D  
6    NaN         U   {05230_U:lmn}                A
```

I want to restructure above so that it looks like below.

**Logic:**

1. Use `id, year, period, freq_no, sequence, data_date` as key (groupby?)
2. Transpose such that `field` becomes column and this column has `value` as its values
3. Create a `combined_note` column by concatenating `note` (for same key)
4. Create a `deleted` column which will show which `note` or `value` was deleted based on `transaction_type D`.

**Output:**

```
          id  year period freq_no sequence  file_date  data_date  05210  \
0  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180331  200.0   
1  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180605   20180330    NaN   

   05220  05230                combined_note              deleted  
0    NaN    NaN  {05210_B:ABC}{05210_U:DEFF}        note{05210_U:DEFF} #because for note 05210_U:DEFF the trans_type was D  
1  200.0  100.0   {05220_U:xyz}{05230_U:lmn}  note{05220_U:xyz}|05230 #because for note {05220_U:xyz} trans_type is D, we also show field (05230) here separated by pipe because for that row the trans_type is D
```

I think this can be done by using `set_index` on `key` and then restructruing other columns but I wasn't able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended having to do this with a merge.
Logical Steps:

1. Group DataFrame by all fields except note and value. This is to preserve the field and transaction columns to not be affected by the aggregation.
2. Add a deleted column.
3. First DataFrame that contains the aggregation of the notes(deleted as well).
4. Second DataFrame to transform field and value to multiple columns.
5. Merge first and second data frame on the index.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

pd.set_option('display.height', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

# url = "https://pastebin.com/raw/nkDHEXQC"
csv_string = b"""id,year,period,freq_no,sequence,file_date,data_date,field,value,note_type,note,transaction_type
abcdefghi,2018,A,001,001,20180605,20180331,05210,200,,,A
abcdefghi,2018,A,001,001,20180605,20180331,05210,,B,{05210_B:ABC},A
abcdefghi,2018,A,001,001,20180605,20180331,05210,,U,{05210_U:DEFF},D
abcdefghi,2018,A,001,001,20180605,20180330,05220,200,,,U
abcdefghi,2018,A,001,001,20180605,20180330,05220,,U,{05220_U:xyz},D
abcdefghi,2018,A,001,001,20180605,20180330,05230,100,,,D
abcdefghi,2018,A,001,001,20180605,20180330,05230,,U,{05230_U:lmn},A
"""
data = io.BytesIO(csv_string)
df = pd.read_csv(data, dtype={'freq_no': object, 'sequence': object, 'field': object})

# so the aggregation function will work
df['note'] = df['note'].fillna('')
grouped = df.groupby(
    ['id', 'year', 'period', 'freq_no', 'sequence', 'data_date', 'file_date', 'field', 'transaction_type']).agg(['sum'])

grouped.columns = grouped.columns.droplevel(1)
grouped.reset_index(['field', 'transaction_type'], inplace=True)
gcolumns = ['id', 'year', 'period', 'freq_no', 'sequence', 'data_date', 'file_date']


def is_deleted(note, trans_type, field):
    """Determines if a note is deleted"""
    deleted = []
    for val, val2 in zip(note, trans_type):
        if val != "":
            if val2 == 'D':
                deleted.append(val)
            else:
                deleted.append('')
        else:
            deleted.append('')
    return pd.Series(deleted, index=note.index)


# This function will add the deleted notes
# I am not sure of the pipe operator, i will leave that to you
grouped['deleted'] = is_deleted(grouped['note'], grouped['transaction_type'], grouped['field'])

# This will obtain all agg of all the notes and deleted
notes = grouped.drop(['field', 'transaction_type', 'value'], axis=1).reset_index().groupby(gcolumns).agg(sum)

# converts two columns into new columns using specified table
# using pivot table to take advantage of the multi index
stacked_values = grouped.pivot_table(index=gcolumns, columns='field', values='value')

# finally merge the notes and stacked_value on their index
final = stacked_values.merge(notes, left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={'note': 'combined_note'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
final
          id  year period freq_no sequence  data_date  file_date  05210  05220  05230                combined_note         deleted
0  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180330   20180605    NaN  200.0  100.0   {05220_U:xyz}{05230_U:lmn}   {05220_U:xyz}
1  abcdefghi  2018      A     001      001   20180331   20180605  200.0    NaN    NaN  {05210_B:ABC}{05210_U:DEFF}  {05210_U:DEFF}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works on the given data set but fails on this https://pastebin.com/raw/2JPpvB7x. If you replace `freq_no` with `001` in 3rd row then it works fine. I'm unable to figure out what's going wrong here.

Comment: The only difference I am seeing is a NaN in the first row, what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Correct but on running the code with the [given data set](https://pastebin.com/raw/2JPpvB7x) I get this error. `ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names`.

Comment: I ran on both python2.7 and python3.5 and cannot reproduce your error. Output: https://pastebin.com/raw/baZMaQXz

Comment: I was getting the error on pandas 0.20.0. I don't notice it on 0.22.0.